# How to make the DRF ( Django-REST-Framework) Token persist so that it does not get lost after each page refresh?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, api, django-rest-framework

**NOTE- I am not using Python, Django, Templates for the front end. Just Pure HTML+jQuery+AJAX**

I have successfully implemented getting a User Based Token from the API Backend, Set it in Header File for the subsequen requests and work on the data provided by the API. But the problem is that whenever I refresh the page, the `Authentication` token is not there in the Header and I have to provide credentials again to access the API. Every time I refresh the page, the token is removed. How can I stop this?

This is my code for setting the Header using jQuery+AJAX.

```
$('#login').click(function () {
        //Send a POST Request to the URL for Token specified for User
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                username: $('#username').val(),
                password: $('#password').val()
            },
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-api/api-token-auth/',
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res.token)
                //Initialize the Ajax for the first time
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    //Set the headers so that these will be in every HTTP Request
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": 'Token ' + res.token
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As very basic setup, you can save your token in local storage when you get it from server

```
success: function (res) {
      console.log(res.token)
      localStorage.setItem('authToken', res.token)
}
```

and get it from there whenever you want `localStorage.getItem('authToken')`. It will persist between page refreshes and even when browser / system is restarted.

To automatically set it up for ajax, execute this code on page load

```
       $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                "Authorization": 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('authToken')
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks bud! but what if there are more than one users on the same computer? Won't it compromise the security? Is't it better to save it in session storage than to the local?

Comment: You're welcome :). Well it depends upon your application. Local storage is more persistent than session storage. Session storage only persist in tab/window it was created in. but you should not only rely on it and implement extra security measures. You should give user option to logout manually, and on logout destroy token from client side as well as invalidate it on server side. Secondly you should not issue tokens with very long validity period like sessions. Keep lifespan of token very short (like 5 or 10 min) and keep refreshing it in background as long as user is using application.